# setcustomvalidity posição do tooltip

Tags: html, css

Eu tenho dois inputs com setCustomValidity.

No primeiro input o tooltip do setCustomValidity aparece corretamente alinhado a esquerda, como na imagem abaixo:

[image]

Mas no outro input ele aparece alinhado ao meio, sendo que o resultado que eu esperava era estar alinhado a esquerda como no primeiro input, como na imagem abaixo:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <label>Code:</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="3" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(); "/>

        <label>Description:</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="3" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity();" style="width: 500px;"/>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Alguém sabe como posso alinhar o tooltip do setCustomValidity à esquerda?

Comment: Repare que ele na verdade parece estar alinhado ao centro do input! Vc pode fazer um teste fácil colocando inputs de vários tamanhos que vc vai perceber melhor isso. Além disso esse "estilo" de tooltipe pode variar de Browser para browser, sendo diferente no Chrome, no FireFox, no Edge etc. O ideal é vc criar seu próprio tooltipe

Comment: @hugocsl Valeu! Realmente cada browser tem seu padrão de implementação, e até então não vi como mexer na propriedade diretamente, nem no css, para ajeitar as posições.

Comment: Se vc conseguir customizar vai ser com classes -webkit- ou -moz- vc vai ter que ver quais são os atributos do user-agente para cada vendor-prefix... por isso dei a ideia de vc não usar o modelo default e partir para criar seu próprio modelo. O Bootstrap por exemplo tem um modelo padrão, justamente pra não depender do browser do usuário e mostrar sempre o mesmo tooltipe independe do browser https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/

Comment: @hugocsl Realmente, o melhor é criar um próprio modelo, até porque o custo do tempo fica BEM menor, obrigado!